# DB2 Export/Import DEL command for DB2 on Cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, db2, export, ibm-cloud

I need to Export data from DB2 table into text format and after that import the file from IBM COS (aka S3) file storage into DB on Cloud.

The data details:

- UTF-8
- Data types: Timestamps, Strings (with **New Lines inside** => multiple lines), Numbers, Floats
- No CLOB or BLOBs

**What Export and Import command should I use?**

I tried

**Export**

```
db2 EXPORT TO table1.del OF DEL modified by codepage=1208 SELECT * FROM table1
```

The first line of the *table1.del*:

```
"blah",6,"1",766,"Y","blah","2022-01-24-08.53.09.000000","blah","3,766",1
```

**Import**

```
INSERT INTO table1 FROM EXTERNAL 'table1.del' USING
  (CCSID 1208 s3('s3.xxxxxx.cloud',
  's3-access-key-id',
  's3-secret-access-key',
  'bucket-name')
  )
```

It found the file but Error during file processing (it seems that Import try to get the whole first line and insert into the first column. Specifying *fillRecord* option did not help):

```
bad #: input row #(byte offset to last char examined) [field #, declaration] diagnostic, "text consumed"[last char examined]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1: 1(182)[1, VARCHAR(256)] missing field - fillRecord not enabled, ""blah",6,"1",766,"Y","blah","2022-01-24-08.53.09.000000","blah","3,766",1"[1]
```

**Load**

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('IMPORT from "S3::s3.xxxxxx.cloud::s3-access-key-id::s3-secret-access-key::bucket-name::table1.del" OF DEL modified by codepage=1208 
 INSERT into TABLE1 ')


FAILED [Code: -2062, SQL State:      ]  An error occurred while accessing media "DB2REMOTE".  Reason code: "0x870f01bb".. SQLCODE=-2062, SQLSTATE=     , DRIVER=4.25.1301
```

**Extra questions:**

1. Can I load IXF files from the S3 storage? Or only TXT file format is supported?
2. I also tried to CATALOG DB2 STORAGE as described here https://blog.4loeser.net/2017/08/combining-db2-and-cloud-object-storage.html
   But LIST STORAGE ACCESS gives nothing and

   ```
    CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('LOAD from db2remote://bucket-name-alias//table1.ixf OF IXF  INSERT INTO table1');
   ```

Return:

```
    FAILED  [Code: -1652, SQL State:      ]  File I/O error occurred.. SQLCODE=-1652, SQLSTATE=     , DRIVER=4.25.1301
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to

```
    INSERT INTO table1 FROM EXTERNAL ....
```

Details:

1. Import DEL file sould have EOL - LF only, not LF-CR;
2. NULL values defined as NULL string;
3. Column's Delimeter - TAB;
4. CSV file has Header string, so SKIP 1 row option added;
5. Added some options to the IMPORT COMMAND:

   ```
   INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL 'table1.csv' USING
   (CCSID 1208 s3('s3.xxxxxx.cloud',
                's3-access-key-id',
                's3-secret-access-key',
                'bucket-name')
    ) 
    DELIMITER x'09'
    LFINSTRING TRUE
    CRINSTRING TRUE
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
    SKIPROWS 1
    NULLVALUE 'NULL'
    QUOTEDVALUE DOUBLE
    CTRLCHARS FALSE
   ```

   )